# How can I update state in a component from a hook where that hook is used without causing infinite re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component:

```js
const CallScreen = () => {
  const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
 
  const updateTimerColor = () => {
    setCallEnded(true);
  };

  const clock = useTimer(
    callStartTime,
    callLength,
    callTimeOut,
    timerReady,
    connectionState,
    updateTimerColor,
  );
```

Then in `useTimer` I want to call `updateTimerColor` when certain conditions are met. The problem is is that when the state updates, the hook is called again and because the conditions under which `updateTimerColor` is called are the same, the component infinitely re-renders.

How can I update state in `CallScreen` from the hook without creating an infinite loop?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also include how  you call updateTimerColor but maybe checking if callEnded changed value since last call before calling setCallEnded might prevent the infinite loop.

```
 const updateTimerColor = () => {
   //No need to set it again if the value did not change
   if(!callEnded) {
     setCallEnded(true);
   }
 };
```